# Position:absolute image inside position:relative not showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Inspecting the image in IE8 shows that it's being rendered - but with:

```
height: 0;
width: 0;
```

I can remember coming across this problem before and fixing it - but i can't for the life of me remember how!

Any ideas?

Comment: Showing code and working example will speed up answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the image to display: block;

Answer (score 0):

Seems your reset.css is not working, for IE you begin by redefining the height to 1px for all elements.

Comment: What reset.css sets all elements to 1px height? That's seems ridiculously stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the parent element having position relative within which the absolutely positioned images are present, has a defined height and width.

Comment: Answers with source code on Codepen, JSFiddle or any other equivalent online examples get more votes. Alternatively, you can write code in your answer with the provided formatting tools.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).